# Simplify and/or optimize sql query with INTERSECT or HAVING

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have the following data:

```
 tag_id | taggable_id 
--------+-------------
      1 |           1
      2 |           1
      3 |           1
      4 |           1
      1 |           2
      2 |           2
      5 |           2
      6 |           2
      7 |           3
      8 |           3
      9 |           3
     10 |           3
```

And I want to bring all the taggable_ids which are in a group of tag_ids AND in another group AND another... (max 4 groups).
For example:

- if I search all the taggable_ids with tag_id 1 or 7 AND tag_id 4 should return just 1
- if I search all the taggable_ids with tag_id 1 AND tag_id 6 AND tag_id 2 or 8 should return just 2
- if I search all the taggable_ids with tag_id 8 AND tag_id 5 should not return ids

In a gross way(for the second example), the query is the following:

```
SELECT taggable_id FROM taggings WHERE tag_id in (1)
INTERSECT
SELECT taggable_id FROM taggings WHERE tag_id in (6)
INTERSECT
SELECT taggable_id FROM taggings WHERE tag_id in (2,8)
```

I think simplifying it, it looks like:

```
SELECT taggable_id FROM taggings WHERE tag_id in (1,2,6,8)
GROUP BY taggable_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

but I'm wondering if can be done in a simpler way. Any thoughts?

Comment: your second query looks about as simple as it gets.

Comment: `(tag_id, taggable_id)` is defined unique, right?

Comment: Your query does not agree with your description. And your 2nd one is *not* equivalent as the first. It would be prudent to present a consistent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be cast as a case of **[relational division](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/relational-division/info)**. We have assembled an arsenal of query techniques under this related question:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879)

Depending on data distribution and other factors, this may be fastest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT taggable_id
FROM   taggings t1
JOIN   taggings t2 USING (taggable_id)
JOIN   taggings t3 USING (taggable_id)
WHERE  t1.tag_id = 1
AND    t2.tag_id = 6
AND    t3.tag_id IN (2, 8);
```

Assuming unique `(tag_id, taggable_id)`, `DISTINCT` is actually not needed for the example. But it might be necessary with other (list) predicates.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3cb07/3) (building on @Clodoaldo's, thanks).

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3cb07/1)

Your second query fails if the tuple `(8, 2)` is inserted. Here is one solution although I don't know if simpler then the `intersect` one:

```
select taggable_id
from taggings
where tag_id in (1,2,6,8)
group by taggable_id
having
    array_agg(tag_id) @> array[1,2]
    and
    array_agg(tag_id) && array[6,8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is not equivalent to the first.  Change the `having` clause to:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tag_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN tag_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN tag_id IN (2, 8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

As for performance, test the queries to see which performs better.  The advantage of the `having` approach is you can add more and more complex conditions without having a significant impact on performance.